# how can we open a word file with specific page number in c sharp?

Tags: c#, interop, ms-word

How can we open a word file with specific page number?

This is the the code I used to open the file:

```
public static Application Open(string fileName)
{
    object fileNameAsObject = (object)fileName;
    Application wordApplication;
    try
    {
        wordApplication = new Application();
        object readnly = false;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        wordApplication.Documents.Open(ref fileNameAsObject, ref missing, ref readnly);

        return wordApplication;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogEntry log = new LogEntry();
        log.Categories.Add("Trace");
        log.Message = ex.ToString();
        Logger.Write(log, "Trace");
        throw new System.IO.FileLoadException("File cannot be opened");
    }
    finally
    {
        wordApplication = null;
    }
}
```

How can I use the `Vba` code `Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToFirst, Count:=3, Name:=""`  equivalent in `C#` to get the page that I want? Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent C# interop would be:

```
object what = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage;
object which = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToFirst;
object count = 3;

wordApplication.Selection.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref count, ref missing);
```