# Programmatically jumping to specific page in a docx file

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, docx

I have a usecase where my tool will open a docx file and then jump to a specific page in that docx. Can it be done using C#?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I have not tried anything. I am a Java developer. But, it seems that it's not possible with Java. So, I am thinking of doing it in .Net way.

Comment: @Raj, if you're new to .Net, I recommend searching web for "word automation using C#" e.g. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can we open a word file with specific page number in c sharp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870797/how-can-we-open-a-word-file-with-specific-page-number-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via something like what have been done at [how can we open a word file with specific page number in c sharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870797/how-can-we-open-a-word-file-with-specific-page-number-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thank you very much. But, the above code seems to VB code. I need C# version. Can it be ported to C#?

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to incorporate your solution in my tool.