# Powershell resize image in word document

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I've added an image to a word document using powershell. How can I resize?

```bsh
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

$Word.Visible = $True

$Document = $Word.Documents.Add()

$Selection = $Word.Selection

$Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture("$imagelocation")|Out-Null

$Selection.InlineShapes.Height = 50

$Selection.InlineShapes.Width = 50
```

But I get the following errors:

```
Exception setting "Height": 
"The property 'Height' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."

Exception setting "Width": 
"The property 'Width' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to set the `Height` and `Width` on the collection that contains *all* inline shapes.

Use the specific `InlineShape` object returned by [`AddPicture()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.inlineshapes.addpicture) instead:

```
$newInlineShape = $Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture("$imagelocation")
$newInlineShape.Height = 50
$newInlineShape.Width = 50
```

Comment: great! Do you know, how to 1) put it on a specific page and 2) position it on the page?

Comment: @sberezin By assigning the [appropriate range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806763/select-page-in-docx-using-c-sharp) to `$Selection`